# HTTP POST fails against a Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

I have a spring controller with a single request mapping.

```
@Controller
public class HandoffController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandoffController.class);
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/a/path/handoff", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView home() {
        logger.info("We have just hit HandoffController. About to go to index.html...");
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

When I do an http GET, it's successful.
[image]
When I do a post it fails.
[image]
Even in the failing case we do get the log statement, interestingly. In my use case GET is not sufficient, I need to make POST work.

I've played around with my spring security, but no dice so far.

Comment: Is the mapping for /index.html [GET-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100261/requestdispatcherforward-throws-request-method-post-not-supported-when-fo)?

Comment: kinda hard to see where you're posting to since you've redacted the URI, but the previous comment eludes to the underlying issue.  You're forwarding a POST request to `/index.html`.

Comment: You cannot forward a POST request to `index.html`. You should use a redirect (which eventually will issue a `GET` request for the `index.html`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coworker suggested that I redirect to a GET only mapping, like so:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/firstGuy", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView firstGuy() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/onlyGet");
}

// no post, otherwise forward to index.html would fail
@RequestMapping(path = "/onlyGet", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView onlyGet() {
    return new ModelAndView("forward:/index.html");
}
```

This did the trick (it just so happens nothing is actually being posted, so we don't lose anything. It's just that the person pinging us HAS to do a POST because of reasons, and so we're allowing that to happen).

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you used "forward" to forward the request to `/index.html`.

This resource may not support POST requests in your program. Therefore, a 405 error will occur.